# openpty() not recognised in C++ Xcode

Tags: c++, c, xcode, pty

I have a weird error occurring, where if I use the function `openpty()` in C program it compiles ok but if I have the exact same code in a C++ program I get a compiler error:

```
error: 'openpty' was not declared in this scope
```

Both Xcode projects have the exact same code in one file (main.c and main.cpp respectively).

How can I fix this error?

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int gps_fdm, gps_fds;
    char slave_port_name[256];
    int open_res = openpty(&gps_fdm, &gps_fds, slave_port_name, NULL, NULL); // compiler error here
    return 0;
}
```

*Taking advice from the comments I have attempted to include `pty.h`. Unfortunately this creates a compiler error `error: pty.h: No such file or directory`.

Comment: 1. This is not c++ at all, 2. What compiler are you using, 3. Where is `pty.h`?

Comment: The project is going to be in C++ this is the raw skeleton. This function openpty() needs to be used in our C++ project.

Comment: @iharob when I include `pty.h` I get another compiler error: `no such file or directory`. I am on a Mac OS using Xcode as my IDE

Answer (score 0):

According to the [man page for `openpty()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/openpty.3.html), you don't include some hypothetical "pty.h". You need to `#include <util.h>`.